# camel noop on java process restart - is it being trigger?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using :
from("file:/somedir?noop=true&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified}")

in order to read a file every time it is being change.
Will the route be trigger also when the java process is being restart , and the file was not change from last reading ? if not - is there a way to do this with camel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a persistent idempotent repository, there is some out of the box such as a file based etc.

- http://camel.apache.org/file2

Otherwise if you restart the application then it "do not remember" and will read the file again regardless if it was modified or not in the mean time.